# Suppose G is a finite and simple group which acts transitively on S. Given that $k \equiv |S| > 1$, prove $|G|$ divides $ k!$

Tags: group-theory

I think they key point here is to prove that $G$ must be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_k$ then we would be done.

I am quite lost in trying to do so. Since $G$ acts transitively on $S$, can't we just say directly that $G$ induces some type of permutation, so it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_k$? I know something is wrong with this argument, but I can't quite see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have an action of a group $G$ on a set $X$, then we can immediately construct a group homomorphism $f:G\to S(X)$, with $S(X)$ the group of permutations of $X$.

If $G$ is simple then $f$ must be injective, so it is in fact an isomorphism from $G$ to a subgroup of $S(X)$.

If, moreover, $X$ is finite of cardinal $n$, then $S(X)$ is also finite and of cardinal $n!$. Using Lagrange's theorem, we see that the order of $G$, which is equal to the order of the image of $f$, divides $n!$.

Comment: Why is it the case that if G is simple then f must be injective?

Comment: I propose you spend some time thinking about it.

Comment: Take $g, h \in G$ then suppose that $f(g)x = f(h)x$, we have $f(gh^{-1})(x) = f(g)f(h)^{-1}(x) = x$. Then, $gh^{-1}$ must be identity as well, implying $g = h$. I am sorry but I think I still got lost why we need G is simple.

Comment: You *need* to use at some point that the group is simple. In the argument you wrote in that comment yo deduced that $gh^{-1}$ is the identity from the fact that $f(gh^{-1})x=x$ for some (or all, I cannot tell...) $x$: that just does not work.

Comment: @Shar What can you say about the kernel of $f$?

Comment: I got it now! Sorry for not getting it. So, kernel of $f$ must be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then, it must be that the kernel of $f$ only contains the identity.